# Removing anything but <a> and <img> tags using c# and regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am working with chunks of html code, but I am only interested in `<a>` and `<img>` tags. Could you advise how to remove anything other than `<a>` and `<img>` tags from the input string using c# and regex?

I did try HAP (HTML Agility Pack), but parsing some content runs into StackOverflowException.

**Guys, I am not asking for help with HTML Agility Pack. I am after Regex solution.**

Comment: I did try HAP (HTML Agility Pack), but parsing some content runs into StackOverflowException.I did try HAP (HTML Agility Pack), but parsing some content runs into StackOverflowException.

Comment: did you try any regexes?

Comment: I am not that familiar with regex, hence I posted question here.

Comment: I see you are trying to remove everything that is not <a> and <img> from the received string, can't you actually remove <a> and <img> from it?

Comment: No, as an output I need a string that contains a list of all a and img tags.

Comment: You should show what you have tried with HTML Agility Pack or investigate some time in regular expressions, which, by the way, are  [bad candidates for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: [Do not parse html with regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). If you want some help with HTML Agility Pack, you'll need to provide some code that causes the overflow exception.

Comment: First, please show your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want <img> and <a>

Create a Regex with the two of them and the alternation operator |

```
(<img.+?>|<a.+?>.+?<\/a>)
```

And in the replacement you can use the group \1

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, like everyone said on your comments, I do not advise you to use regex to parse HTML (it's kinda of a rule), but if you really need it... (for whatever reason that might be...)

I'd say that you could parse that string and get every  and  tag on the HTML string, and save it on a List.

Regex for those are quite simple (you can really expand them by learning a bit of regex.. it's not that hard and i am not going to do all the work for you, mainly when I have no clue what the HTML looks like)

```
"<img.+?>"
"<a.+?>.+?</a>"
```

Test it here with some html (remove the "" for testing it): http://regexpal.com/

For the C# code itself, I'm pretty sure you can find it quite easily.